# Looping over a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, loops, repeat, shuffle

I'm just puzzled with this one, it's a Haskell loop-sort-of-thing which I can't figure out how to write. Basically, I've defined three functions **split**, **riffle** and **shuffle**.

```
split :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
split xs = splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs

riffle :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
riffle xs [] = xs
riffle [] ys = ys
riffle (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:riffle xs ys

shuffle :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
shuffle 0 xs = xs
shuffle n xs = shuffle (n-1) (riffle a b)
    where (a, b) = split xs
```

Basically split just splits a list in half, riffle is supposed to 'interlace' two lists, so for example:

```
riffle [1,2,3] [4,5,6] = [1,4,2,5,3,6]
```

And shuffle is to iterate the amount of splitting and riffling of the list items. Now I need to define a function **repeats** which outputs how many iterations of shuffle would it take to get the original list again. The function is defined as such:

```
repeats :: [Int] -> Int
```

I'm just stuck as to how you can perform a loop over the shuffle... I think it has something to do with list comprehension but I couldn't get anything. I have yet to try a lambda expression but I don't think it's necessary. By the way, the shuffle should be done on lists with even number of items. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way of solving this is to take advantage of laziness and use `iterate` to generate the infinite list of iterated shuffles of the input.

```
> iterate (uncurry riffle . split) "ABCDEF"
["ABCDEF","ADBECF","AEDCBF","ACEBDF","ABCDEF","ADBECF","AEDCBF","ACEBDF", ...]
```

The first element of the list is the original one, so we drop that with `tail`, then use `takeWhile` to get the ones that were different from the original.

```
> takeWhile (/= "ABCDEF") . tail $ iterate (uncurry riffle . split) "ABCDEF"
["ADBECF","AEDCBF","ACEBDF"]
```

Now, you just need to take the `length` of that list and add one to get the required number of shuffles.

Comment: You can also generate the list with `tail $ iterate` as @hammar describes, and use [`elemIndex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex) to find the index of recurrence.

Answer (score 5):

In many cases you can use an infinite list rather than a "loop".  This is one of them.

The prelude function "iterate" repeatedly applies a function to a value, so (from memory)

```
iterate f x = [x, f x, f (f x), f (f (f x)) ....]
```

So if you apply "iterate shuffle" to a starting list then you get the progressive shuffle. Then use takeWhile to find the first entry in the list that is equal to your starting point,and then "length" to find out how long that is.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, iteration is most commonly expressed using recursion rather than through looping.

This is often done by using an inner function that tells you how to do the iteration, and then simply calling the inner function with the appropriate arguments.

Perhaps you can fill in the gaps in the following code?

```
repeats xs = iter 1 (...) where
    iter n ys = if ys == xs
        then n
        else iter (...) (...)
```

An alternative approach is to exploit Haskell's laziness and do it with an infinite list, using the higher-order function `iterate`, which repeatedly applies a function to an initial argument:

```
repeats xs = (...) $ takeWhile (...) $ iterate (shuffle 1) (...)
```

Although `iterate` returns an infinite list, we will only ever use a finite portion of it, and so we don't get into an infinite loop.